# ImageStatic in OpenLayers 6 does not fit a given extent when shown on the map

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I am using ImageStatic in OpenLayers to display an image on the map using EPSG:3857. I noticed the image pixels were stretched in some cases and were overlapping the specified image extent by 1px towards the east.

[image: ImageStatic overlapping the extent]

<sub>A red polygon feature representing the extent and a dark transparent image (512x512 px)</sub>

In this example, the image aspect ratio (1) matches the extents aspect ratio (1.0000000000000475) almost completely. It seems like OL is trying to match the aspect ratio by increasing the width of the image which leads to stretching/overlapping.

Code to reproduce:

```js
  let extent = [1584998.2185214162, 5816552.104388772, 1589890.1883316676, 5821444.074199023]
  let projection = ol.proj.get('EPSG:3857');

  // static image
  let imageLayer = new ol.layer.Image({
    source: new ol.source.ImageStatic({
      url: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/71/Black.png',
      imageExtent: extent,
      projection: projection,
      imageSize: [512, 512], // for some reason the image gets stretched to 513 x 512?
    }),
    opacity: 0.5
  });

  // display extent as poly
  let poly = new ol.geom.Polygon([
    [
      [extent[0], extent[3]],
      [extent[0], extent[1]],
      [extent[2], extent[1]],
      [extent[2], extent[3]],

    ]
  ]);

  let vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
      wrapX: false,
      projection: projection,
    }),
    style: new ol.style.Style({
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: 'rgba(255,0,0,1.0)',
        width: 2,

      })
    })
  });

  vectorLayer.getSource().addFeature(
    new ol.Feature({
      geometry: poly,
    })
  );

  // create map
  let map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
      }),
      vectorLayer,
      imageLayer

    ],
    view: new ol.View({
      center: [extent[2], extent[1]],
      zoom: 18
    })
  });

  // source extents are still the same but they differ on the map
  console.log("poly: " + vectorLayer.getSource().getExtent());
  console.log("image: " + imageLayer.getSource().getImageExtent());
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w5gcvb3n/1/)

The extent used in the example matches the extent of a zxy tile.

Is there a way to display an ImageStatic so it fits a given extent better? Or maybe by providing a upper-left corner point and resolution in meters?

I was able to avoid the problem to an extent by rounding the extent values,
but the problem reappeared on locations elsewhere in the world and/or at different resolutions.

Comment: The image is stretched (or reduced) to what should be the best integer value to fit the extent, but for some reason it is always rounded up instead of being rounded to the nearest integer https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/main/src/ol/source/ImageStatic.js#L139

Comment: @Mike Is this a bug then? And what would be the solution?

Comment: II think it should be considered a reproduceable bug (it happens with OL's own tile coordinate calculation https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-forked-y4njr)  A few nanometers difference in extent width and height should not add a whole pixel in width to a square image.  Rounding when reducing the width would risk a zero width which would be invalid, so I will raise an issue and suggest always stretching in either the x or y dimension as appropriate, with rounding.  Reducing width to fit does not seem a good idea anyway as the quality loss cannot be regained when zooming in.

Comment: @Mike Thank you Mike, I think I can work with that. The solution would be to deduct half of pixel worth of meters from the most eastern point when specifying the image extent. However, I do not consider this solution to be complete, as the image extent is now incorrect.

Comment: or you could simply round the extent coordinates to the nearest meter.

Comment: @Mike I tried doing that by rounding the values `Math.round(extent/ metersPerPixel) * metersPerPixel`, but the problem persists (I am also dealing with submeter resolutions).

Comment: I think with more than 2 decimal places and the way JavaScript floating point works means there is a 50% chance of this happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@Mike](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/102658/mike) I was able to work around the problem.

The problem arises when [OpenLayers 6 uses a ceiling function](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/main/src/ol/source/ImageStatic.js#L139) to determine the target width to display the image.

I ended up subtracting half of resolution(in meters) from the original extents most eastern point when passing it to ImageStatic.

`extent[2] = extent[2] - metersPerPixel/2`

I found this, at least in my case, to be the simplest and most consistent solution to display the image the way I wanted.